# Manga/manhwa about a guy who lived alone and was reincarnated into a family of craftsmen

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I'm looking for a manga/manhwa that's about a guy who lived alone his whole life then when he died, he was reincarnated because a god liked that he lived by himself.

When he gets reincarnated he is born into a family of craftsman and makes things like fridges burners and stuff like that. I can't remember any more details than that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: It came out around August/September, So around then. I read it on a website thst Translates manga/manhwas. I don't want to disclose the website since it might get my post removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *[A Single Aristocrat Enjoys a Different World - The Graceful Life of a Man Who Never Gets Married](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/8j68iyw/dokushin-kizoku-wa-isekai-wo-ouka-suru-kekkon-shinai-otoko-no-yuuga-na-ohitori-sama-life)*.

> Toshinori Dokuraba, 35 years old. A so-called single aristocrat in Japan who **enjoyed a single life without wife and children**, even though he was tall, handsome, highly educated and had a high income. One day, he died alone at home.
>
> However, **he was liked by Hitorigami, the God of another world, and was able to reincarnate in that world**. Reborn as Zirc Louren with skills and blessings from the God, he lived a new rosy life in a different world - then he turned 28 years old and enjoyed the single life again...
>
> This is a story about the life of a single aristocrat who never gets married even if he reincarnates in another world

Synopsis covers most of the details. He lives alone and suddenly dies and meets two gods. One chastises him for living alone; the other takes a liking to him and offers to reincarnate him in another world with some skills.

[image: meeting the gods]

While in the other world he uses a combination of his skills and knowledge from the other world to create appliances, including a refrigerator.

[image: Fridge]

Comment: This is it, Thank you so much!